# selenium driver close when the new window pop out

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I run the test

First I login and the window close and open a  new one.

but the test failed.

it show Unable to get browser (NoSuchDriver).

Is it means my driver is been closed?

How to solve it?

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: what about some research on your own? Selenium FAQ? Google?